# Modifying the @grid.assets in rails datagrid Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid, scope

I have a very granular ACL. I can not extend the Grid class to work with my module so I thought I impose the ACL (Access list) at the controller level.

Basically at the sales_reports_controller.rb I have

```
 @grid = SalesReportsGrid.new(params[:sales_reports_grid]) do |scope|
      scope.page(params[:page])
  end
```

I need to only show the sales that belong to the user with an specific role. Access lists is in an array and if I can go through the `@grid.assets` then I can only add the records to the `@grid` that I need to and pass it to the view.

Or if I can do the loop when I am getting the `scope` and filter the records.

Now is there anyway that I can do something like this or similar:

```
 aa = @grid.assets
      grid = []
      aa.each do |a|
        if user_acls.include?(a.access_list_id)
          grid.push a
        end
      end
 @grid.assets = grid
```

The above loop is not going to work, as assets is not going to accept anything. I get the following error.

```
undefined method 'assets=' for #<SalesReportsGrid:0x007fe9e79203a0>
```

So my best bet is adding the loop here

```
 @grid = SalesReportsGrid.new(params[:sales_reports_grid]) do |scope|
          scope.page(params[:page])
 end
```

Which I am not sure how.

Thanks.

**Edit: (Possible Solution)**
I have added the

```
a = []
   assets.each do |asset|
    if user_acls.include?(asset.access_list_id)
      a.push asset
    end
   end
   assets = a
```

at the view level and it works (partial copy).
It would be better to apply the restriction at the controller level though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass assets back to grid.

Do the following in you controller:

```
@assets = @grid.assets.select do |a|
  user_acls.include?(asset.access_list_id)
end.page(params[:page])
```

And render the assets in the following way in template engine:

```
datagrid_table(@grid, @assets)
```

In general filtering ACL at ruby level will cause serious performance problem. You can only use it if you are sure that `@grid.assets` will never get higher than 1000.

If you are able to move it to SQL - do it like:

```
@grid = SalesReportsGrid.new(params[:sales_reports_grid]) do |scope|
  scope.where(access_list_id: user_acls).page(params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Perfect. I move the SQL. I had to change my entire sales DB structure. But it worth it. I have got one more question which I make a new question for it in stackoverflow and will let you know. thanks again mate.